# Object Data comparison tool

Tags: data-migration

**Issue background:**
We have an org which is huge in size and used by multiple business groups. So we are executing a project to split the org. We created a new org and planned to move the subset of data specific to the business group (the new org will be only be used by an specific business group)

We migrated the data into new org (there are about 80+ objects), now we need to compare the data accuracy between the master org and the new org.

Is there any reliable tool which we can use to compare the data object wise (may be export the data from both orgs and then compare)

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can execute the following *algorithm* with any number of integration tools like jitterbit, informattica etc.

1. Establish connections to both orgs.
2. Create a "Pull" or "Retrieve" job for org 1 that specifically does not pull object ID's, User Id's, or created/modified timestamps as these will necessarily be different. ***Utilize the tool's crypto tools to write a generated field that is the SHA256 (or some other hash function) of the entire record).*** One job per object.
3. Create the same kind of job for the second org; only this time have your tool check the csv/db it created from the first org. Only write rows that are cryptographically different.

If you do this twice, swapping org order, and find that there are 0 rows after step 3 on both runs, you've ensured that the same number of rows, and the data within those rows (that is not a org specific ID or timestamp) is identical.

No, unfortunately, I do not know of an automated tool for this. Could probably whip one up on heroku pretty easy though. You'd have to pay for the postgress db intermediary and you're more than likely to hit bulk/regular api limits with 80 objs.

edit: You'll want to downcase your input data before hashing it. #hardFought.

Comment: Instead of  SHA256 i would suggest you do concatenation. it would be easy to debug just in case there are differences

Comment: On the contrary, i find that minute differences in data are maddeningly hard to identify in concatenated strings.

Comment: If you want to figure out what is difference between two records how you can do it with SHA256 or hashed record.

Answer (score 0):

You can use excel connector but repeating process for 80+ objects would be pain  https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000025263&language=en_US